# Sum key-values pairs in a text file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, for-loop

My for-loop is not working properly.
I want to group the same keys and sum their values.
For example, sum all of the `yes` values and display it in one row.
The information in game.txt is looking like this:

```
yes 5
maybe 9
yes 2
maybe 10
maybe 7
no 25
yes 1
```

the print looks like this;

```
{'no': '25', 'yes': '1', 'maybe': '10'}
```

And my code looks like this;

```
test_scores = {}

filename = input("Enter the name of the score file: ")
file = open(filename, mode="r")

print("Contestant score: ")

for file_line in sorted(file):
    key, value = file_line.split()
    if key not in test_scores:
        test_scores.update({key: value})

print(test_scores)
```

So what seems to be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: What did you want the print to look like? You're using a dictionary, so each key can only appear once.

Comment: Do you want to sum the values?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. I need to sum every yes, no and maybe together, so I need a print that has maybe 26 no 25 yes 8, in alphabetical order, in separate lines. I am pretty new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
for file_line in file:
    key, value = file_line.split()
    test_scores[key] = test_scores.get(key, 0) + int(value)

for k, v in sorted(test_scores.items()):
    print(k, v)
```

`dict.update(...)` just overrides the values. You could use a `collections.Counter` which handles, well, counting more naturally:

```
from collection import Counter

test_scores = Counter()
# ...
for file_line in file:
    key, value = file_line.split()
    test_scores[key] += int(value)
    # update would work, too, here
    # test_scores.update({key: int(value)})
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked well. I just had to put + int(value) in order to be able to sum the values.